# How do you stop a thread in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a very simple thread in python:

```
threading.Thread(target=self.clock).start()
```

All I want to do is be able to delete the current one and make a new one (that will be set to 0 seconds), so it can start counting again, but no matter what I try I cannot stop the original thread from counting.

Comment: I’m just looking for a very simple way I.e one command, also my I’m not using a thread class

Comment: There is no simple way. A thread runs until the `target` function returns. And you *are* using a thread class: `threading.Thread`.

Comment: my own thread class*

Comment: This question was already asked. Check this: - [Kill a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread) You set a value which the thread will check. You can also use a flag to stop it.

Comment: You say it's "very simple," but the one line of code that _starts_ the thread doesn't prove anything. It's what the thread _does_ that defines whether it is simple or sophisticated. Any time you have a question about a thread, the code that the thread executes and the code executed by other threads with which it interacts usually is _much_ more pertinent than the code that launches it.

Comment: unless I want to find out how to delete it... in which case the code it executed is irrelevant...

Answer (score -1):

Unlike the processes that can be [terminated](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=terminate#multiprocessing.Process.terminate), the thread will run until the function returns.